# Django pagination - with unlimited queries

Tags: django, django-pagination

I am using Django pagination - and it works great ;) ...

But in some cases I have a URL with queryies - and when i use the default template setup for pagination - it wont work..

```
<div class="pagination">
    <span class="step-links">
        {% if contacts.has_previous %}
            <a href="?page={{ contacts.previous_page_number }}">previous</a>
        {% endif %}

        <span class="current">
            Page {{ contacts.number }} of {{ contacts.paginator.num_pages }}.
        </span>

        {% if contacts.has_next %}
            <a href="?page={{ contacts.next_page_number }}">next</a>
        {% endif %}
    </span>
</div>
```

How can I do it ? ..

My url can look like this: 
http://www.example.com/tag/?tag=fewa&met=23&g=2&page=2
or
http://www.example.com/tag/?tag=fewa&g=2&t=ewq&page=2

What can I do at the pre and next position?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<a href="?page={{ products.previous_page_number }}{% for key,value in request.GET.items %}{% ifnotequal key 'page' %}&{{ key }}={{ value }}{% endifnotequal %}{% endfor %}">forrige</a>
```

I got IT ;)